# What is the easiest way to write truffle tests in typescript?

Tags: truffle, truffle-test, typescript

I read about [Typechain](https://github.com/ethereum-ts/truffle-typechain-example), but the configuration is rather verbose and generally feels like a very custom solution:

> Everytime you change contracts you need to run yarn generate.